# Unable to use viewmodel concept in mvc4 to enter data from same view and display data in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having some hard time in understanding viewmodel concept in mvc 4. I know to create simple registration form. Also i know to display data using view. I want to perform both in one view but could not achieve it. This is what i am trying.
This is model.

```
 public class Table
        {  
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public int pincode { get; set; }
        }
```

This is my view code.

```
@model c3card.Website.Models.Table

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutC3Card.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Table</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pincode, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pincode)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pincode)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pincode)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
}
```

my major doubt goes here. Above form works fine. If i want to display item then I should put this line of code `@model IEnumerable<c3card.Website.Models.Table>` but if I put this `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)` will get error. So I want to post data to database and I want to display in same view. How can I achieve this?

As soon as I enter data like name, address, pincode and when I click on submit button I want to display all data in below table. This is what I am trying to achieve. I can achieve by using `viewbag` concept but I am avoiding `viewbag` concept.

It seems to be working fine without errors. Now last thing is how to return model to the view?

Please note: GetDetails is method which is in DAL layer. I have written linq query to retrieve data based on parameters. If you have any concerns let me know.

Thanks in advance.

This is my view code.

```
@model c3card.Dal.EDModel.MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutC3Card.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ts_upld_doc</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.upload_document.upld_clientid)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.upload_document.upld_employeeid)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.upload_document.upld_empcitizenid)

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now problem is submit button is not firing up.
This is my view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ts_upld_doc upload_document { get; set; }
        public IList<ts_upld_doc> Upload_List { get; set; }

    }
```

Table ts_upld_doc contains many fields like client_id,emp_id,citizen_id etc so i am not posting here.

This is my viewmodel.

```
public class MetaDataClass
    {
        public virtual int upld_docid { get; set; }
        public virtual string upld_docname { get; set; }
        public virtual string upld_contentlabel { get; set; }
        public virtual string upld_contentvalue { get; set; }
    }

   public class DeleteDocApproval
   {

       public ts_upld_doc upload_document { get; set; }
       public IList<ts_upld_doc> Upload_List { get; set; }
       public IList<MetaDataClass> test { get; set; }
   }
```

This is my index method with GET

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            DeleteDocApproval model = new DeleteDocApproval()
            {
                upload_document = new ts_upld_doc(),
                Upload_List = new List<ts_upld_doc>(),
                test = new List<ts_upld_doc>()
                {

                }

            };


        }
```

Actually to fill my gridview i have some big query something like this. But i am not able to write it inside the actuion method.

Comment: Is there somebody to help me on this?

Comment: in last foreach is it  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) or
 @Html.DisplayFor(item=> item.name) ? can you correct it an check

Comment: i want to display all the items. model => model.upld_employeeid

Comment: My project is 3 layered it contains business layer,Data access layer and one more layer which contains controllers,views and js files etc. So in which layer i should implement viewmodel? i am using ADO.net in DataAccess layer.

Comment: you already have Table model in c3card.Website.Models namespace i.e folder path.you can place there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show Form and List on same view, You need to create `ViewModel` for this.

So this is your class.

```
 public class Table
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int pincode { get; set; }
    }
```

Now Create ViewModel, Which contain this class and list of this class.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public Table Registertable { get; set; }
        public IList<Table> UserList { get; set; }
    }
```

To use this viewmodel in your view. write this code.

```
@model IeInTouch.Web.Models.MyViewModel
```

I'm not writing all code for form.

It is just sample.
Inside your form

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Registertable.name)
```

To display date for table header.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Registertable.name)
```

Now run foreach loop to show the data.

```
@foreach(var user in Model.UserList)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem  => user.address)
}
```

Now pass this viewmodel from action

```
 public ActionResult Test()
        {
            MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel()
            {
                Registertable = new Table(),
                UserList = new List<Table>(){
                    new Table(){
                        name="xyz",
                        id=1
                    },
                    new Table(){
                        name="ABC",
                        id=2
                    }
                }
            };
            return View(myViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally i need to know how to return model to the view in above scenario. I tried something and i posted above

Comment: @Niranjan: Yes . you should accept `MyViewModel` in POST action to get form data .

Comment: Yes i tried i posted some code above. Now only first field i am able to recieve in post method. My url looks like this when posting back http://localhost:62328/DeleteDocument/Create?client_id=1. I am not getting rest of the fields. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Mr Amit kumar Now i am able to recieve all the fields. Some error was there. Can you tell me how can i return model from the controller to the view?

Comment: Yes i will try. Should i implement in GET method also. Because when the page first loads i dont want to display anything. After hitting submit button only i want to display all values. So should i return model from the GET method also?

Comment: Thanks a lot AmitKumar. but in get method what should i put? i dont want to display anything so... You hardcoded some values. In that place what should i write?

Comment: That was just for smaple . you don't need to write hard coded values . But to show list, you need to pass list of data

Comment: yes i simply initialized model and passed through get method. Now error gone. Now i studies concept of view models. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the above example inside the test action method if i had to write some complex query then how can  i do this? Because as soon as page loads i want to display some info in gridview for this i am using different tables.

Comment: @Niranjan: Add those attributes in `MyViewModel` and then assign the value to those attributes.

Comment: I tried as above but i am not sure where to put my query

Comment: @Niranjan: Don't edit my answer, rather than edit your question.

Comment: instead of  new Table(){
                        name="xyz",
                        id=1 if i had to write some complex query then how can i write?

Comment: Sorry Amit i could not notice. I am trying to delete contents from your answer what i entered just now. please delete contents i entred here because i am not able to delete it. Thank you